# How to get the file name of javascript loaded in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have a HTML file. In that file, I am referencing two external javascript files. Among those, one javascript file has error in it (mostly compilation errors). And I have written `onerror` method in another javascript file which does not have any error. Now when I open the HTML file in browser, obviously `onerror` will be called. The contents in that method will be executed. Here my actual thought, I would like to print javascript file name which has error in it in an `alert(-)` placed inside `onerror` method of another javascript file.

If I put `arguments.callee` statement inside `alert(-)`, then it is printing current `onerror` method content. If i put arguments.callee.caller , then it is printing null.

Is there any way to find file name of javascript loaded which has errors in it through programatically, specially in javascript?

Comment: You might want to look at the [doc for the onerror event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty well answered in https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror. Especially look at this:

> funcRef is a reference to a function. When the function returns true,
>   this prevents the firing of the default event handler. Function
>   parameters:
>
> ```
> Error message (string)
> URL of the script where the error was raised (string)
> Line number where error was raised (number)
> Column number for the line where the error occurred (number)
> Error Object (object)
> ```

This results in:

```
window.onerror(msg, URL, line, col, e) {

       alert("Error in " + URL + " at " + line + "/" + col);

}
```

I recommend to not use alert for showing script errors but the `console` object.